# Scala map explicit type

Tags: scala, generics, higher-order-functions

I'm new in Scala and programming in general.. I have troubles with the Scala map function..

The simple signature of the map function is: def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): List[B]

So i guess the B of map[B] is generic and i can explicit set the type of the result?

If i try to run the code:

```
 val donuts1: Seq[Int] = Seq(1,2,3)
 val donuts2: List[Int] = {
    donuts1.map[Int](_ => 1)
  }
```

i got the error message "expression of type int doesn't conform to expexted type B"

I don't understand the problem here.. Could someone explain the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `map()` signature quoted in your question is a simplified/abbreviated version of the full signature.

```
final def map[B, That](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
```

So if you want to specify the type parameters (which is almost never needed) then you have to specify both.

```
val donuts1: List[Int] = List(1,2,3)
val donuts2: List[Int] = donuts1.map[Int,List[Int]](_ => 1)
//donuts2: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1)
```

> and i can explicit set the type of the result?

Not really. The type parameter has to agree with what the `f` function/lambda returns. If you specify the type parameter then you're (usually) just asking the compiler to confirm that the result type is actually what you think it should be.

Comment: That `map` signature in the question is for the `map` method in from `MonadOps` which does not have the implicit parameter. I suspect that IntelliJ is getting confused and showing that signature instead of the one from `TraversableLike` which does have the implicit parameter.

Comment: @Tim It's also the one shown in Scaladoc by default. That's probably why the question specifies "the _simple_ signature".

Comment: "and i can explicit set the type of the result?" – Well, there sort of is a way with `collection.breakOut`. For example, `val donuts2: List[Int] = Seq(1,2,3).map(_ * 2)(collection.breakOut)`

Comment: @jwvh Cool - Thank you!